# How to save view part with EMF

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a Eclipse RPC project. I need to save and restore everything of all views . I am not using EMF in my project so i can not use all EMF API's.

Now what can I use is `IMemento`. `IViewPart` have a `saveState` method with `IMemento` as a parameter.

I am invoking `saveState()` and try to put this in view.

Sample code:

```
@Override
public void saveState(IMemento memento) {
   ColorBarModel model =  _multiColorBarContainer.getColorBar().getColorBarUIModel().getModel();
   boolean isCutOff = _multiColorBarContainer.getColorBar().getColorBarUIModel().isCutOffEnabled();
   String colorMapName = model.getColorMap().getColorMapName();
   memento.putString("colorMapName", model.toString());
   memento.createChild("colorMapName1", model.toString());
   String selectionsMomento = memento.getString("colorMapName");
   IStructuredSelection ss = new StructuredSelection(memento.getChild("colorMapName1"));
 }
```

I need to save model which is a reference of class (`ColorBarModel.java`  is model for my view), so that i can save the model state and restore it on invoking.

But `IMemento` only provide `putString()`, `createChild()` method

Can someone guide me to how can I save the class object through `IMemento` and restore it when ever needed?

**I am able to save the reference ID of that class , but I am not sure how to fetch property and behaviour of that class through `referenceId` in string form.**

Is it possible to fetch that somehow?

Comment: What sort of information do you need to store? IMemento is only intended for relatively small amounts of strings.

Comment: I want to store the entire model information, any suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save large amounts of data you should put in the plugin state location. You get this with:

```
IPath path = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

`bundle` is the `Bundle` class for your plugin. You can get this from the `BundleContext` passed to the plugin Activator or using

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

The state location is in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins` directory. Just use normal Java file I/O operations to read and write data in this location.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but can you plzzz elaborate how to save the entire model information in Ipath, i am able to find the bundle but not sure how to store. It would be great help

Comment: My model contains approx 10 to 20 variable which i need to store and wanted to restore in other launch..So this is a tedious for me..And unfortunately my project is not emf model , so i can not use EMF API;s :(

Comment: I don't know anything about your code so I don't see how I can advise any further.

Comment: I am sorry greg, My apology..  Can you give an example of normal java model.Like any view has some data that data provided by some ModelImpl.So i need to store that Model and restore that...Kindly provide some pseudo code that store java object state through Ipath..That would be great help

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy, you can use Googles GSON To convert the model into JSON and store that as a String.
Then you can use GSON again to load a defined class from the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

The `IMemento` provides an interface to store your view state in XML using a hierarchy. you can:

- call the methods of your model and try to represent it in a XML structure to be recreated in the init method of the view
- store your model on the disk and reference it somehow (e.g. the path) in the memento
- serialize your complex object to bytes, convert it to a Base64 `String` and put it in the memento

Answer (score 0):

I have created the class `SimpleModelSerializer` to be able to easily write and read EMF models to and from difference formats. `IMemento`s are handled with the `readMemento` and `writeMemento` methods. The class can easily be extended to work for other formats.

It is **very** minimal and can only handle simple models. The following are some of the restrictions:

- **Non-containment references are not handled**.
- **Sub-typing of feature values is not handled**.
- EPackages must be in the global package registry.
- It probably just crashes on a lot of valid models.
- No validation is performed.
- Very minimal support for extended metadata.
- A lot of other things...

Despite this it is useful for saving small simple things like view configuration.

This is the code:

```
/**
 * Contains code for reading and writing EMF models to and from other formats.
 */
public class SimpleModelSerializer {
    public interface ModelReader {
        List<String> getMultiAttribute(String name);
        String getAttribute(String name);
        String getDefaultAttribute(String name);
        List<ModelReader> getChildren(String name);
    }

    public interface ModelWriter {
        void setAttribute(String name, String value);
        void setDefaultAttribute(String name, String value);
        void setMultiAttribute(String name, List<String> values);
        ModelWriter createChild(String name);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void setFeature(EObject o, EStructuralFeature feature, Object value) {
        if (feature.isMany()) {
            ((List<Object>) o.eGet(feature)).add(value);
        } else {
            o.eSet(feature, value);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static List<?> getFeature(EObject o, EStructuralFeature feature) {
        if (feature.isMany()) {
            return (List<Object>) o.eGet(feature);
        } else {
            return Collections.singletonList(o.eGet(feature));
        }
    }

    public static <T extends EObject> T readMemento(IMemento mem, EClass cls, Class<T> instCls, ExtendedMetaData meta) {
        return readCastedObject(cls, instCls, new MementoReader(mem), meta);
    }

    public static <T extends EObject> List<T> readMementos(IMemento mem, String name, EClass cls, Class<T> instCls, ExtendedMetaData meta) {
        return readObjects(cls, instCls,  new MementoReader(mem), name, meta);
    }


    public static <T extends EObject> List<T> readObjects(EClass cls, Class<T> instCls, ModelReader reader, String name, ExtendedMetaData meta) {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ModelReader childReader : reader.getChildren(name)) {
            result.add(instCls.cast(readObject(cls, childReader, meta)));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static <T extends EObject> T readCastedObject(EClass cls, Class<T> instCls, ModelReader reader, ExtendedMetaData meta) {
        return instCls.cast(readObject(cls, reader, meta));
    }


    public static EObject readObject(EClass cls, ModelReader reader, ExtendedMetaData meta) {
        if (meta == null) meta = ExtendedMetaData.INSTANCE;

        EObject obj = EcoreUtil.create(cls);

        for (EStructuralFeature feature : cls.getEAllStructuralFeatures()) {
            if (feature.isTransient()) continue;

            String name = meta.getName(feature);

            List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();

            if (feature instanceof EAttribute) {
                EAttribute attr = (EAttribute) feature;

                List<String> attrs;
                if (attr.isMany()) attrs = reader.getMultiAttribute(name);
                else if (name.equals(":0")) attrs = singletonList(reader.getDefaultAttribute(name));
                else attrs = singletonList(reader.getAttribute(name));

                for (String attrText : attrs) {
                    if (attrText != null) {
                        values.add(EcoreUtil.createFromString(attr.getEAttributeType(), attrText));
                    }
                }
            } else if (feature instanceof EReference) {
                EReference ref = (EReference) feature;

                for (ModelReader childReader : reader.getChildren(name)) {
                    values.add(readObject(ref.getEReferenceType(), childReader, meta));
                }
            }

            for (Object value : values) {
                setFeature(obj, feature, value);
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }

    public static void writeMemento(IMemento mem, EObject o, ExtendedMetaData meta) {
        writeObject(new MementoWriter(mem), o, meta);
    }

    public static void writeMementos(IMemento mem, String childName,  Collection<? extends EObject> os, ExtendedMetaData meta) {
        MementoWriter writer = new MementoWriter(mem);
        for (EObject o : os) {
            writeObject(writer.createChild(childName), o, meta);
        }
    }


    public static void writeObject(ModelWriter writer, EObject obj, ExtendedMetaData meta) {
        if (meta == null) meta = ExtendedMetaData.INSTANCE;

        EClass cls = obj.eClass();

        for (EStructuralFeature feature : cls.getEAllStructuralFeatures()) {
            if (feature.isTransient()) continue;

            String name = meta.getName(feature);

            if (feature instanceof EAttribute) {
                List<String> outputValues = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Object e : getFeature(obj, feature)) {
                    if (!Objects.equals(e, feature.getDefaultValue())) {
                        String textValue = EcoreUtil.convertToString((EDataType) feature.getEType(), e);
                        outputValues.add(textValue);
                    }
                }

                if (feature.isMany()) {
                    writer.setMultiAttribute(name, outputValues);
                } else if (!outputValues.isEmpty()) {
                    if (name.equals(":0")) {
                        writer.setDefaultAttribute(name, outputValues.get(0));
                    } else {
                        writer.setAttribute(name, outputValues.get(0));
                    }
                }
            } else if (feature instanceof EReference) {
                for (Object value : getFeature(obj, feature)) {
                    if (value != null) {
                        writeObject(writer.createChild(name), (EObject) value, meta);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class MementoReader implements ModelReader {
        private final IMemento memento;

        public MementoReader(IMemento memento) {
            this.memento = memento;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDefaultAttribute(String name) {
            return memento.getTextData();
        }

        @Override
        public String getAttribute(String name) {
            return memento.getString(name);
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> getMultiAttribute(String name) {
            IMemento[] childMems = memento.getChildren(name);
            List<String> attrs = new ArrayList<>(childMems.length);
            for (IMemento mem : childMems) {
                attrs.add(mem.getTextData());
            }
            return attrs;
        }

        @Override
        public List<ModelReader> getChildren(String name) {
            return Arrays.stream(memento.getChildren(name)).map(MementoReader::new).collect(toList());
        }
    }

    private static class MementoWriter implements ModelWriter {
        private final IMemento memento;

        public MementoWriter(IMemento memento) {
            this.memento = memento;
        }

        @Override
        public void setAttribute(String name, String value) {
            memento.putString(name, value);
        }

        @Override
        public void setMultiAttribute(String name, List<String> values) {
            for (String value : values) {
                memento.createChild(name).putTextData(value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ModelWriter createChild(String name) {
            return new MementoWriter(memento.createChild(name));
        }

        @Override
        public void setDefaultAttribute(String name, String value) {
            memento.putTextData(value);
        }
    }
}
```